# will the string in the define directive be copied when it is used in multiple places?

Tags: c, gcc

Will the string defined by a statement like:

```
#define CADENA "stringy string\n"
```

be duplicated in all the .c files where it is being used ? If that is the case then the executable code will grow considerably which is not a good thing. Consider this code:

```
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ cat str.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define CADENA "stringy string\n"

void printit(char *s) {
    printf("%s",s);
}
void main(void) {
    printit(CADENA);
    printit(CADENA);
}
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ gcc -o str str.c
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ ./str
stringy string
stringy string
[niko@dev1 snippets]$
```

Will the compiler create 2 constant strings in this case or just one ?
If it is just a single one then how do you control if the content of the #define directive is copied or a unique reference is made ? Does GCC has any switch or command line option for this?

I checked out what the preprocessor generates, and indeed, the string is duplicated:

```
[niko@dev1 snippets]$ gcc -E str.c | tail 
# 5 "str.c"
void printit(char *s) {
 printf("%s",s);
}
void main(void) {
 printit("stringy string\n");
 printit("stringy string\n");
}
[niko@dev1 snippets]$
```

In a real use case:

```
if (some condition) {
    fatal_error(__FILE__,__LINE__,"Can't write to socket");   
}
```

I am using the constant **__FILE__** for debugging purposes, should I better store it in a variable to reduce the code size?

Comment: Many compilers use "string pooling" in which it discovers you have used that exact string already and uses a pointer to the shared (constant) string.

Comment: so how do I know if my compiler does or does not use string pooling ?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie got it. 'string pooling" are the keywords to search for. We may close this question now.